# Usage limit for Google Maps URL

Tags: google-maps-urls

1. Is there any usage limit (request/day) for Map URLs like https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=parameters
   and https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&parameters
2. Can we use these Map URL in intranet based enterprise application for locating an address?
3. Is there any requirement to buy a premium plan and generate an API Key in such cases ?
4. Is there any IP tracking enabled for Map URLs to detect the incoming request from an application ?

Comment: [RTFM](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage-limits)

Answer (score 0):

Google maps api is limited to 2500 requests per day and 50 requests per second. Beyond this, you should pay. here is the link that you can have more informations :

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-limits?hl=FR

You can use these apis in your intranet application. If a device is connected to internet, you can locate an address directly. If you want to use these apis without any connection, you should download the plan of the area that you want to use :

https://support.google.com/maps/answer/6291838?co=GENIE.Platform%3DiOS&hl=en

If you don't exceed request limits, no need to buy anything, if you want to buy, there is some basic informations to provide like first name, last name, email address etc...

Comment: Mentioned limits are applicable when you generate an API Key with free plan. But my question here is, if I don't create any google account/generate a key and simply use the Map URL (https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=parameters) directly in a hyperlink of intranet based enterprise application, then how many such requests will be allowed per day ? Note that I've almost 1K address hyperlinks.

Comment: It is like using a navigator to display a website, I don't think that there is a limit of usage or any obligation to create an account. In one of my applications I use exactly the same think, in a grid by a button I show the location of the client on the map on a navigator without any google account.